# Create empty file using Drive API

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I create this code, using this reference https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/ruby

```
class Drive
  def initialize
    @drive_service                                 = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
    @drive_service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    @drive_service.authorization                   = authorize
  end

  def create_file
    data = { 'name': "My new Sheet #{Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')}",
             'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' }
    @drive_service.create_file(data).execute
  end

  def share_file
    "to be filled"
  end

  def list_files
    response = @drive_service.list_files(page_size: 10, fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)')
    puts 'Files:'
    puts 'No files found' if response.files.empty?
    response.files.each do |file|
      puts "#{file.name} (#{file.id})"
    end
  end
end
```

The method `list_files` works well, but the `create_file` return me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from quickstart.rb:79:in `<main>'
    1: from quickstart.rb:60:in `create_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/google-api-client-0.53.0/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:895:in `create_file': unknown keywords: :name, :mimeType (ArgumentError)
```

I created it based on this create method reference: https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#create_file-instance_method
but I still can't get it to work, what could be wrong?

I tried changing the creation to: `@drive_service.create_file(file_object = data).execute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compare your code,

```rb
data = { 'name': "My new Sheet ...
@drive_service.create_file(data).execute
```

vs. the [documented method signature](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#create_file-instance_method).

```markdown
`create_file(file_object = nil, enforce_single_parent: nil, ignore_default_visibility: nil, include_permissions_for_view: nil, keep_revision_forever: nil, ocr_language: nil, supports_all_drives: nil, supports_team_drives: nil, use_content_as_indexable_text: nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, user_ip: nil, upload_source: nil, content_type: nil, options: nil) {|result, err| ... } ⇒ Google::Apis::DriveV3::File`
- file_object (Google::Apis::DriveV3::File) (defaults to: nil)
```

The first argument should be an instance of `Google::Apis::DriveV3::File`, but you are passing a `Hash`.

Comment: you're right, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/docs/usage-guide.md#hashes):

> When supplying hashes for request objects. If it is the last argument
> to a method, some versions of Ruby will interpret the hash as keyword
> arguments. To prevent this, appending an empty hash as an extra
> parameter will avoid misinterpretation.
>
> ```
> file = {id: '123', title: 'My document', labels: { starred: true }}
> file = drive.create_file(file) # Raises ArgumentError: unknown keywords: id, title, labels
> file = drive.create_file(file, {}) # Returns a Drive::File instance
> ```

In your code, just add `{}` as 2nd parameter for create_file.

**From:**

```
@drive_service.create_file(data)
```

**To:**

```
@drive_service.create_file(data, {})
```

Let me know if this works on your end.

Comment: this is documentation for a v2 version, but it works fine even though I'm using v3.
I just don't understand one thing, am I missing something important as a parameter or should it work like this?